# Even integer in ternary representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

Suppose $(d_0,d_1...d_k)_3$ is the ternary representation of a even integer $n$. Show that there is an even number values $d_0...d_k$ that are odd, whenever $n$ is even.

I have tried decomposing different even integers using a (base$*$integer)$+$remainder method, and tried to find a pattern in the remainders. But nothing seemed apparent

i.e: $14$ in ternary is $(112)_3$ has $2$ odd values.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: I have tried decomposing different even integers using a (base*integer)+remainder method, and tried to find a pattern in the remainders.

Comment: You should edit this attempt into the question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that your integer is

$$n=(d_md_{m-1}\ldots d_1d_0)_{\text{three}}=\sum_{k=0}^m3^kd_k\;.$$

$3^k$ is odd for each $k\in\{0,\ldots,m\}$, so the term $3^kd_k$ is odd when $d_k$ is odd, and even when $d_k$ is even. If add up $a$ odd and $b$ even integers, what conditions on $a$ and $b$ make the sum odd? even?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\displaystyle n =\sum_{i=0}^k 3^id_i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^k d_i \equiv 0 \pmod 2$